# jQuery datepicker not working in IE9 with dynamic textarea added

Tags: jquery, datepicker, internet-explorer-9, textarea

I have an HTML table with the multiple rows contain the form controls such as input type="text" and textareas. Last column of every is a date field and is of type input and the other fields are textareas. Everything was working fine with default fields and dynamically added rows: I am using the below line to add the dynamic row a table.

$('#DataTable tr:last').after(
       tr
         td align=justify
           textarea rows=1 cols=50
           textarea
         td
         td align=justify
           input type=text id=Date1
         td
       tr);

The date picker added after inserting a new row like below:

$("Date1").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", showOn: "button", firstDay: 1,       showOtherMonths: true, prevText:'<',nextText: '>'});

I recently added the dynamic behavior to increase the textarea height and check the maxlength (since maxlength also is not working in IE9).

The code to add the dynamic behavior to textarea is given below:

$("#DataTable  textarea").keydown(function(e) {
increaseRows(this, e); });

IncreaseRows function is given below:

> function increaseRows(textAreaObj, e) {
>       while(textAreaObj.scrollHeight < textAreaObj.offsetHeight) {          textAreaObj.rows--;         }
>
> ```
>   while(textAreaObj.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
>       textAreaObj.rows++;         }   textAreaObj.rows++;
>
>       var $this = $(textAreaObj);
>       var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');
>       if (!!maxlength) {
>           var text = $this.val();
>           if (text.length > maxlength) {
>               // truncate excess text (in the case of a paste)
>               $this.val(text.substring(0,maxlength));
>               e.preventDefault();
>           }
>       }   }
> ```

With this, the datepicker stopped working. I am able to see the Calendar but cannot pick the date as always.

Any ideas?

Best Regards,
MouliPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved with the below modification from jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjqWy/155/#run

The problem was due to rows attribute which is not supported in IE9. And the JS method is modified as below:

```
function increaseRows(textAreaObj, e) { 
        textAreaObj.oninput = function() {
            textAreaObj.style.height = "";
            textAreaObj.style.height = Math.min(textAreaObj.scrollHeight, 300) + "px";
        };

        var $this = $(textAreaObj);
        var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');
        if (!!maxlength) {
            var text = $this.val();
            if (text.length > maxlength) {
                // truncate excess text (in the case of a paste)
                $this.val(text.substring(0,maxlength));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```